# Are shoes mandatory while playing cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket, equipment

Are shoes mandatory while playing cricket? No doubt it will be difficult without shoes but I would like to know whether it is mandatory or not. Any idea?

Edit: Hundreds of rules are there in Cricket and I would like to know whether a player is allowed to play Cricket (in international level) without shoes or not. Is there a rule regarding this in ICC or MCC laws?

Edit: Here is my point. I used to play tennis ball cricket without shoes. Now a local tournament organizer wants every player in shoes. As I am not familiar, I have problems bowling with shoes. So, I need to file a complaint against this rule. That's why I need to know whether there is anything in ICC rules.

Comment: Presumably this is asking about at a competition level or above? I've seen kids playing cricket without shoes in lots of places!

Comment: What is the benefit that players will get while playing without shoes? you have to mention that, if not, we can ask `Does wearing shirt/pants mandatory in ICC rules?`. Please add some points to make your post valuable. and I forgot one thing, Welcome to Sports.SE :)

Comment: Thanks for understanding, Spinner. You think the organizer is keen about the players security? No, that is not the case here. The reason they are saying is that, without shoes, the bowler will get extra pace! Therefore for uniformity, the want every player in shoes. I think this is not right and I am going to lodge a complaint against the rule. Thanks again, Spinner.

Comment: You are welcome. This would be better posted as a comment or an edit, by the way, rather than an answer - it adds useful information to the original question. It would also be useful if you logged in using the same account that you posted the question on ("Neil"), rather than using a different account for commenting and editing ("user1450378").

Comment: Please see http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts for help with merging your two accounts.

Answer (score 4):

There is no Law of Cricket that specifically requires the use of shoes. (I am reminded of Mark Jefferson's fictional West Indian cricketer *[Hurricane Hamish](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Cricket-World-Hurricane-Hamish/dp/0590636944)*, who found it impossible to bowl in shoes!)

[image]

However, it has to be said that if playing with a cricket ball, it would be **extremely unwise not to wear shoes** - even a relatively slow delivery could cause serious damage to one's feet. It would also reduce one's effectiveness as a fielder, since one would not be able to use them to stop even moderately-struck shots.

In your situation, the tournament organiser likely considers he/she has a duty of care to all players in the competition. This would include wearing appropriate protective equipment - pads, abdominal protectors, gloves, etc. - and at the very least, shoes. I don't think you can reasonably expect him/her to allow you to participate in the tournament without shoes, unless you sign a disclaimer that absolves him/her from all responsibility for what happens to you. Even then I would not be hopeful. If you wish to progress as a cricketer, you'll need to learn to wear shoes whilst playing.